# module not found after cloning git repository

Tags: python, linux, shell, github

I am trying to use this: https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/rouge

I've tried cloning the git repository in the ubuntu for windows terminal, by doing

```
git clone https://github.com/google-research/google-research.git
```

And the cloning seems to go fine.

But when I try to use this script:

```
python3 -m rouge.rouge \
    --target_filepattern="./en_test_CN.txt" \
    --prediction_filepattern="./en_pred_CN.txt" \
    --output_filename="./en_scores.csv" \
    --use_stemmer=true \
    --split_summaries=true
```

It says that there is no module named rouge.rouge:

> /usr/bin/python3: No module named rouge.rouge

I'm really new in this and I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions, and `cd google-research` before running that, or run `pip install rouge/requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Tim Roberts suggested, the `README` specifies running that command from `google-research` root.
Additionally, you should install the package's dependencies.

I've managed to get it running with the following steps:

1. `git clone https://github.com/google-research/google-research.git --depth=1`
2. `cd google-research`
3. `pip install -r rouge/requirements.txt`
4. `python -m rouge.rouge --help`